# bash script case statement not exiting while run from remote node

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, switch-statement

I have a script which does some application restart. its option 2(and only 2) in case statement does not exit at the ;; of the option when run from a remote node in the following format

ssh a@ip /path/script.sh 2 01 05 2019

option 1 and 3 works. option 1 does not have an exit statement still exits the script after execution. 
for option 2 I can see the execution happening till the last echo statement.

the script is as follows

```
source /geneva/app/phts1/.profile

e_name=`echo $HOME|cut -d "/" -f4`

ch=$1
dt=$2
mt=$3
yr=$4


case "$ch" in
  1)
    #..... some script .. working and exiting properly#
    ;;
  2)
    e_sid=`echo $ORACLE_SID`
    e_name=`echo $HOME|cut -d "/" -f4`


    x=12000000
    z=' '
    export GENEVA_FIXEDDATE=$yr$mt$dt$z$x
    process_id=`ps -fu $e_name|egrep 'TM|DConfigAgent'|tr -s " " " "|cut -d " " -f2`


     kill -9 $process_id  &
     cd $HOME/bin
     dconfigadmin -L platform.cfg ## custom application
     DConfigAgent & ## custom application
     sleep 1

     TM -u admin -p password -s $e_sid & ## custom application

     sleep 2
    # clear
     ls -lrt $HOME/log >>aaa.txt
     dt1=`cat aaa.txt|tail -1|tr -s " " " "|tr -s " " "\n" |tail -1`
     rm aaa.txt
     ls -lrt $HOME/log/$dt1>>aaa.txt
     dt2=`cat aaa.txt|tr -s " " " "|cut -d " " -f9|grep ^TM|tail -1`
     rm aaa.txt
     tail -100 $HOME/log/$dt1/$dt2

     echo "execution ends here ...... I can see till this echo statement being printed"
     ;;
  *)
            echo "wrong option"
            exit
            ;;

esac
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Your script got cut off; there is no option 3, or an end to the `case` statement, or anything following the `case` statement (if there was anything).

Comment: 'exit' does not behave like 'break' in a switch statement in C.  You should not expect the script to exit at the end of the case.  You should expect it to not fall thru, though.  In the code you've provided, there is no reason not to expect the echo to execute.

Comment: Hi @chepner, corrected the last part. Can you please have a look now. It doesnot have an option 3 but a wildcard *) case. everything works fine till the script is executed from the server itself. option 2) hangs after the echo statement has been executed only if the script is called from out side the node by doing ssh a@ip /path/script.sh 2 <argument 2> <argument 3> <argument 4>.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell, everything works fine till the script is executed from the server itself. option 2) hangs after the echo statement has been executed only if the script is called from out side the node by doing ssh user@ip /path/script.sh 2 <argument 2> <argument 3> <argument 4>

Comment: Try `ssh -t`.  I have no idea what your "custom applications" are doing, but perhaps their behavior changes if there is a tty present.

Comment: Why do you think the the script is hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script starts background jobs:

```
kill -9 $process_id  &
```

```
DConfigAgent & ## custom application
```

You have not redirected their I/O, so your ssh session is waiting for those commands to finish.

It's not obvious why `kill` needs to be backgrounded but the other command could be given as:

```
nohup DConfigAgent </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```